# Como colocar un sweetlert2 en el controler php

Tags: php, sweetalert2

Tengo un boton submit que hace el envio de un formulario al controler : controller_reg_equipos.php y cuando recorre ese controler , que contiene esto:

```
<?php 

include('../app/config/config.php');

$codigo_patrimonial = $_POST['codigo_patrimonial'];
$tipo_equipo = $_POST['tipo_equipo'];
$descripcion_equipo = $_POST['descripcion_equipo'];



//para que no repita el CODIGO PATRIMONIAl
$codigo_tabla=' ';

$query_codigo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_reg_equipos WHERE codigo_patrimonial = '$codigo_patrimonial'");

$query_codigo ->execute();
              
              $codigos = $query_codigo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              foreach ($codigos as $codigo) {
              $codigo_tabla=$codigo['codigo_patrimonial'];
              
          }
              if($codigo_tabla==$codigo_patrimonial){

                
                echo"<script type='text/javascript' > 
                    alert('Ya existe Codigo Patrimonial ');
                    window.location.href='../almacen/registro_equipos.php';
                    </script>
                    "
                ;

              }

else{

// codigo de mas..
```

entonces al dar click en el boton si me sale la alert que dice "Ya existe Codigo Patrimonial" , esta dentro de un echo como se puede observar , pero cuando le pongo en swal.fire la pagina se queda en blanco y no carga , o existe algun paquete para desarrollador en el controler ?.

Comment: Puedes intentar poner el código pero con el Swal, para verificar como lo estas poniendo, otra cosa estas vinculando el swal para que se pueda usar en tu archivo?

Comment: ya puse el swal.fire o solo swal y la pagina se queda en blanco y obviamente no redirecciona al href.

Comment: Reemplaza tu 'echo' por lo siguiente :  echo "<script> 
    
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            text: 'Ya existe Codigo Patrimonial',
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
          })
        
        window.location.href='../almacen/registro_equipos.php'; 
    
    </script>";}

Comment: Si no funciona quitale el '.fire' al inicio

Comment: ya hize eso pero nada la pagina se queda en blanco y no bota la alerta , recuerda que esta en el controller que seria el backend

Comment: Si te carga la ruta que pusiste en el window location en el url?

Comment: no carga la ruta del window, al dar en el boton se pone en blanco toda la pagina.

Comment: en tu window quita el .href, y creo que tampoco van los puntos para regresar, window.location ='almacen/registro_equipos.php';  puedes probar manual tecleando la url y ver si accede a la pagina para ver si el url es correcto

Comment: ya esta todo los cambios realizados y nada , osea el sweetalert si funciona en todo las paginas siempre y cuando sea frontend pero cuando quiero colocar en el backend que seria los controllers nada sale en blanco al menossss que los pongo con alert simple como esta arriba en el ejemplo y normal hay si sale la alerta pero simple , por eso es mi duda.

Comment: por eso tamben pregunto si hubiera un paquete especial o algo para poder desarrollarlo con otro estilos o algo siempre y cuando sea en el backend

Comment: Tienes el HTML separado del back, o esta mezclado? por ejemplo en un archivo php puedes meter html sin problema, y en la parte superior donde importas los scripts agregas la libreria del swal y te deberia de funcionar (ojo aqui esta el html en un archivo php) o estas utilizando algún framwork?